# convert a server response string to a valid JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I do not have any control over modifying the server endpoint to return a valid JSON.

Endpoint: http://newsrack.in/stories/servelots/iihs_feeds/16.json

sample response data:

```
    `var _nr_metadata = {
      site_base_url : "http://newsrack.in",
      issue_name    : "iihs_feeds",
      category_name : "Chikungunya",
      listing_url   : "/stories/servelots/iihs_feeds/16"
    }
    var _nr_stories = [
       {
    title  : "Delhi: Changing weather conditions cause 25 per cent rise in dengue cases",
    url    : "http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/delhi-changing-weather-conditions-cause-rise-in-dengue-cases/1/1075570.html",
    source : "India Today| Must Read",
    date   : "26.10.2017",
    desc   : "<a href=\'http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/delhi-changing-weather-conditions-cause-rise-in-dengue-cases/1/1075570.html?utm_source=rss\'><img src=\'http://media2.intoday.in/indiatoday/images/stories/dengue305_102617022722.jpg\' align=\"left\" hspace=\"2\" height=\"180\" width=\"305\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\"/><\/a>Usually at this time of the year, the virus becomes inactive due to \ntemperature dip. But experts are witnessing the hostile nature of ades \nmosquitoes."
  },
  {
    title  : "Waste management bye-laws pending approval of LG: Delhi High Court told",
    url    : "http://indianexpress.com/article/delhi/waste-management-bye-laws-pending-approval-of-lg-delhi-high-court-told-4906249/",
    source : "Delhi – The Indian Express",
    date   : "25.10.2017",
    desc   : "<img alt=\"\" border=\"0\" src=\"http://pixel.wp.com/b.gif?host=indianexpress.com&#038;blog=53855017&#038;post=4906249&#038;subd=indianexpressonline&#038;ref=&#038;feed=1\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" />"
  },
  {
    title  : "Alarm bells ringing:194 dengue cases in 2 weeks in district",
    url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/ludhiana/alarm-bells-ringing-194-dengue-cases-in-2-weeks-in-district/486718.html",
    source : "The Tribune",
    date   : "25.10.2017",
    desc   : "Tribune News Service\nLudhiana, October 24\nThe number of dengue cases is rapidly increasing in the district as 194 confirmed cases have been recorded by the Health Department in the past two weeks.\nA total of 309 confirmed cases and 524 suspected cases of dengue have been reported in the district this year till Monday. According to the Health Department, cases are mostly being reported from the areas on Chandigarh Road in Ludhiana. These include 33-foot Road, GTB Nagar, Mundian Kalan, Guru Nanak Nagar, GK Estate, Jamalpur, Sectors 32 and 39. There are chances that the number of dengue cases could be higher than official reports, say residents.\nThe department had recorded 31 confirmed dengue cases till September 22 and 115 cases till October 10 in these places. Apart from these cases, as many as 10 confirmed cases of chikungunya, which is also spread by bite of infected aedes mosquitoes, have been reported here this year.\nHealth team finds mosquito larvae in 438 containers\nHealth Inspector Manpreet Singh ..."
  },
  {
    title  : "Alarm bells ringing:194 dengue cases in 2 weeks in district",
    url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/ludhiana/alarm-bells-ringing-194-dengue-cases-in-2-weeks-in-district/486718.html",
    source : "The Tribune",
    date   : "25.10.2017",
    desc   : "Tribune News Service\nLudhiana, October 24\nThe number of dengue cases is rapidly increasing in the district as 194 confirmed cases have been recorded by the Health Department in the past two weeks.\nA total of 309 confirmed cases and 524 suspected cases of dengue have been reported in the district this year till Monday. According to the Health Department, cases are mostly being reported from the areas on Chandigarh Road in Ludhiana. These include 33-foot Road, GTB Nagar, Mundian Kalan, Guru Nanak Nagar, GK Estate, Jamalpur, Sectors 32 and 39. There are chances that the number of dengue cases could be higher than official reports, say residents.\nThe department had recorded 31 confirmed dengue cases till September 22 and 115 cases till October 10 in these places. Apart from these cases, as many as 10 confirmed cases of chikungunya, which is also spread by bite of infected aedes mosquitoes, have been reported here this year.\nHealth team finds mosquito larvae in 438 containers\nHealth Inspector Manpreet Singh ..."
  },
  {
    title  : "650 new cases of dengue, 48 of chikungunya",
    url    : "http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Delhi/650-new-cases-of-dengue-48-of-chikungunya/article19908528.ece",
    source : "Hindu: Cities",
    date   : "24.10.2017",
    desc   : "More than 1,000 dengue cases reported so far this month"
  },
  '' // Last item -- needed because previous item ends with a comma
]`
```

as you can see the sample data is not valid JSON, i tried the below function, however ended up with unnecessary space in the keys, which is also a problem.
`

```
//Step 1
        function extractjson(strarg){
                var found = [],          // an array to collect the strings that are found
                    rxp = /{([^}]+)}/g,

                    curMatch;
var parsed=[];
                    // step 2: regex to add quotes
                    var objKeysRegex = /({|,)(?:\s*)(?:')?([A-Za-z_$\.][A-Za-z0-9_ \-\.$]*)(?:')?(?:\s*):/g;
                    while( curMatch = rxp.exec( strarg ) ) {

                        found.push( curMatch[0].replace(objKeysRegex, "$1\"$2\":") );
                    }

                //step 3- parse the found data
                for(i=0;i<found.length;i++){
                    try {
                      json = JSON.parse(found[i]);
                    } catch (exception) {
                      json = null;
                    }
                if (json) {

                  //the json is ok
                parsed.push(JSON.parse(found[i]));

                }else{
                console.log("badjson");
      //the json is not ok

                }
            }
            console.log("input length =", found.length, "output length=", parsed.length);

            return parsed;
            }
            }
```

`

Comment: Am not willing to use eval() as this will be used in a production application, need a safer solution.

Comment: Is my answer helpful to you?

Comment: @JustinPowell nope, i wasn't able to get a valid JSON with your code, i have updated the data that fails, please help if you can

Comment: I see, the data had changed since the last time I tried it. The new issue was that there were improperly escaped apostrophes in the data, I have added a line to handle those.

Comment: yes, the data changes daily as it's a news aggregation site giving xml and json outputs, your solution is working, i will confirm shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly naive attempt at parsing...it makes some assumptions about the format of the data (for example it looks for the `_nr_` prefix on variable names). I'd recommend splitting the string up into its various `var` declarations, and then cleaning up each section of data between them before evaluating using `JSON.parse`.

```js
let parseJSON = (text) => {
  let quoteKeysAndParse = (text) => {
     //Quote keys in objects
     let quoted = text.replace(/([\{\[,]\s*)(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?\s*:/g, '$1"$3": ');
     //Remove the "last item" text
     quoted = quoted.replace(/,\s+'' \/\/ Last item[^\]^}]+([\]\}])/g, '$1');
     //Remove improperly escaping of apostrophes
     quoted = quoted.replace(/([^\\])\\'/g, '$1\'');
     //Parse the JSON
     return JSON.parse(quoted);
  }
  
  //Find var declarations
  let declarations = text.match(/var\s+_nr_[^\s]+\s+=\s+/ig), obj = {}, key = null, prevKey = null;
  text = ['',text];
  //For each variable...
  for(let declaration of declarations){
    key = declaration.match(/_nr_[^\s]+/)[0];
    let currentText = text[1].split(declaration);
    text = currentText;
    if(prevKey){
      //Parse the prior split section
      obj[prevKey] = quoteKeysAndParse(text[0]);
    }
    prevKey = key;
  }
  
  //Make sure we process the last section
  if(prevKey){
    obj[prevKey] = quoteKeysAndParse(text[1]);
  }
  return obj;
}

fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/newsrack.in/stories/servelots/iihs_feeds/16.json')
.then(response => response.text())
.then(parseJSON)
.then(data => {
   for(let item of data._nr_stories){
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = `<h3>${item.date} - <a href="${item.url}">${item.title}</a> (${item.source})</h3><p>${item.desc}</p>`;
      document.body.append(div)
   }
});
```

Comment: This worked! i will test with all my test cases and confirm shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working short solution

```js
  // ----------------------- DATA -----------------------
  let code = `
  var _nr_metadata = {
    site_base_url : "http://newsrack.in",
    issue_name    : "iihs_feeds",
    category_name : "Chikungunya",
    listing_url   : "/stories/servelots/iihs_feeds/16"
  }
  var _nr_stories = [
    {
      title  : "Alarm bells ringing:194 dengue cases in 2 weeks in district",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/ludhiana/alarm-bells-ringing-194-dengue-cases-in-2-weeks-in-district/486718.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "25.10.2017",
      desc   : "Tribune News Service\nLudhiana, October 24\nThe number of dengue cases is rapidly increasing in the district as 194 confirmed cases have been recorded by the Health Department in the past two weeks.\nA total of 309 confirmed cases and 524 suspected cases of dengue have been reported in the district this year till Monday. According to the Health Department, cases are mostly being reported from the areas on Chandigarh Road in Ludhiana. These include 33-foot Road, GTB Nagar, Mundian Kalan, Guru Nanak Nagar, GK Estate, Jamalpur, Sectors 32 and 39. There are chances that the number of dengue cases could be higher than official reports, say residents.\nThe department had recorded 31 confirmed dengue cases till September 22 and 115 cases till October 10 in these places. Apart from these cases, as many as 10 confirmed cases of chikungunya, which is also spread by bite of infected aedes mosquitoes, have been reported here this year.\nHealth team finds mosquito larvae in 438 containers\nHealth Inspector Manpreet Singh ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "650 new cases of dengue, 48 of chikungunya",
      url    : "http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Delhi/650-new-cases-of-dengue-48-of-chikungunya/article19908528.ece",
      source : "Hindu: Cities",
      date   : "24.10.2017",
      desc   : "More than 1,000 dengue cases reported so far this month"
    },
  ]
  `

  // --------------------- / DATA ------------------------


  // --------------------- TREATMENT ------------------------

  
  // Add '"' around the property names
  
  code = code.replace(/\n +([a-z_]+) +:/g, '"$1" :').replace(/[\n\r]/g,'');

  // To avoid unecessary ',' in "}, ]"
  
  code = code.replace(/\},[ ]*\]/g,'}]');


  // Split by var (keeping var name)
  
  code = code.split(/ var(?=[a-z_ ]+= [\[\{])/);
    
  // The result to feed
    
  let result = {} ;

  // Treat each var
  
  code.forEach( d => {

    d = d.trim();
    if (!d) { return }
    
    // Separate var name and var value
    // Faster?
    let index = d.indexOf('=');
    let var_name = d.substr(0, index).trim();
    let var_value = d.substr(index+1, d.length).trim();

    // Parse the value
    
    try 
    {
      result[var_name] = JSON.parse(var_value);
    } 
    catch(error)
    {
      console.error(error);
    }
  })
  
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: i like this approach, i guess i missed a small part in my question, the end of response also has an empty string, because of which the `JSON.parse()` is failing, below is the end of data from response, `{
    <data ... >  },
  ' ' // Last item -- needed because previous item ends with a comma
]` The single quotes and the comment line is playing a spoiler