# Javascript regex to parse JSON string with property values in html

Tags: javascript, json, regex, parsing, jsonlint

i have data in the below format, is not a valid json and am trying to convert using regex, for details see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925591/convert-a-server-response-string-to-a-valid-json-using-javascript) which i've tried, but the parse won't go through.
The problem is that the response string also contains html, var and trailing commas. below is the failing test data.
The expected output should be a valid JSON to use in the rest of my application
I do not have any control over modifying the server response.

```
`var _nr_metadata = {
    site_base_url : "http://newsrack.in",
    issue_name    : "iihs_feeds",
    category_name : "Chikungunya",
    listing_url   : "/stories/servelots/iihs_feeds/16"
  }
  var _nr_stories = [
    {
      title  : "Alarm bells ringing:194 dengue cases in 2 weeks in district",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/ludhiana/alarm-bells-ringing-194-dengue-cases-in-2-weeks-in-district/486718.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "25.10.2017",
      desc   : "Tribune News Service\nLudhiana, October 24\nThe number of dengue cases is rapidly increasing in the district as 194 confirmed cases have been recorded by the Health Department in the past two weeks.\nA total of 309 confirmed cases and 524 suspected cases of dengue have been reported in the district this year till Monday. According to the Health Department, cases are mostly being reported from the areas on Chandigarh Road in Ludhiana. These include 33-foot Road, GTB Nagar, Mundian Kalan, Guru Nanak Nagar, GK Estate, Jamalpur, Sectors 32 and 39. There are chances that the number of dengue cases could be higher than official reports, say residents.\nThe department had recorded 31 confirmed dengue cases till September 22 and 115 cases till October 10 in these places. Apart from these cases, as many as 10 confirmed cases of chikungunya, which is also spread by bite of infected aedes mosquitoes, have been reported here this year.\nHealth team finds mosquito larvae in 438 containers\nHealth Inspector Manpreet Singh ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "650 new cases of dengue, 48 of chikungunya",
      url    : "http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Delhi/650-new-cases-of-dengue-48-of-chikungunya/article19908528.ece",
      source : "Hindu: Cities",
      date   : "24.10.2017",
      desc   : "More than 1,000 dengue cases reported so far this month"
    },
    {
      title  : "Dengue cases mount to 5,870 in Delhi",
      url    : "http://indianexpress.com/article/cities/delhi/dengue-cases-mount-to-5870-in-delhi-this-season-4903035/",
      source : "Delhi – The Indian Express",
      date   : "23.10.2017",
      desc   : "<img alt=\"\" border=\"0\" src=\"http://pixel.wp.com/b.gif?host=indianexpress.com&#038;blog=53855017&#038;post=4903035&#038;subd=indianexpressonline&#038;ref=&#038;feed=1\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" />"
    },
    {
      title  : "Nilavembu Kudineer safe, efficacious, confirms National Institute of Siddha",
      url    : "http://www.deccanchronicle.com/lifestyle/health-and-wellbeing/221017/nilavembu-kudineer-safe-efficacious-confirms-national-institute-of-siddha.html",
      source : "",
      date   : "22.10.2017",
      desc   : "Chennai: Nilavembu Kudineer is safe and effective to treat dengue and other viral fevers and one need not have any qualms in consuming this herbal concoction for immediate relief, the National Institute of Siddha (NIS) functioning under the Union Ayush ministry, here has assured. This institute plans to take up a full-fledged study for global reach of this traditional medicine.\nNilavembu kashayam has been in use for over half-a-century at Government Siddha Medical College, Palayamkottai. It is one among the 32 types of internal medicines described in the Siddha system of medicine. &quot;The nilavembu kudineer, now used for the prevention and management of dengue fever has been explained in the Siddha literatures several centuries ago. There are many research papers on nilavembu kudineer for the treatment and prevention of dengue and other viral diseases. Based on the research studies conducted by our National Institute of Siddha, 70 per cent prevention has been proven against dengue and other viral ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Dengue count hits 902 in city",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/chandigarh/dengue-count-hits-902-in-city/485318.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "22.10.2017",
      desc   : "Tribune News Service\nChandigarh, October 21\nWith two deaths at city hospitals, the number of dengue patients has touched 902. According to the Heath Department, the dengue threat will stay for next fortnight.\nDr Gaurav Aggarwal, anti-malaria officer, said 61 malaria and 58 chikungunya cases had also been reported. Last year, the dengue count in the city was 1,246.\n“Next 15 days are crucial. Residents need to be cautious. The weather is congenial for the breeding of aedes aegypti mosquitoes that cause dengue. As the days progress, dengue cases will start declining,” said Dr Gaurav Aggarwal.\nHe added dengue cases were reported from densely populated areas in Dhanas, Ram Darbar, Daddu Majra, Burail besides Sectors 15 and 25. “Since it  is a notifiable disease, the hospitals will have to inform the UT Heath Department within 24 hours,” said Dr Aggarwal. The Heath Department is planning to take strict action against the hospitals for any kind of laxity on their part. “First, we will sent them a notice. It ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "‘Nilavembu kudineer’, a much sought-after elixir",
      url    : "http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/tamil-nadu/nilavembu-kudineer-a-much-sought-after-elixir/article19894225.ece",
      source : "Hindu: National",
      date   : "21.10.2017",
      desc   : "GSMCH has served it to 8.63 lakh persons this year"
    },
    {
      title  : "Two more succumb to vector-borne disease",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/delhi/dengue-sting/484758.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "21.10.2017",
      desc   : "Tribune News Service\nNew Delhi, October 20\nTwo more persons have fallen prey to dengue in the national Capital taking the tally of deaths from the vector-borne disease this season to five.\nThe last two fatalities took place at city government-run Lok Nayak Jayaprakash (LNJP) Hospital which has alone reported over 860 cases of dengue and two deaths.\nAccording to the latest municipal report, tabulated by the South Delhi Municipal Corporation, the number of people affected by the mosquito -borne disease this season till October 14 has reached 5,220.\nA 12-year-old boy, who died due to dengue shock syndrome at the Sir Ganga Ram Hospital on August, was the first victim in the Capital this year. Of the total 5,220 positive cases of dengue, 2,564 were residents of Delhi whereas the rest were from other states. Of the 2,564 Delhi cases, 757 were reported this month, as per the civic body.\nSimilarly till October 14 the figures of malaria and chikungunya stood at 1062 and 683 respectively. According to the report, ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Over 23 per cent of susceptible population gets infected",
      url    : "http://www.deccanchronicle.com/nation/politics/201017/over-23-per-cent-of-susceptible-population-gets-infected.html",
      source : "",
      date   : "20.10.2017",
      desc   : "Chennai: Dengue has generated much attention and debate, as well, but it appears to be rather difficult to manage this menace without collective efforts, it appears.\nAlthough several Opposition parties including the DMK, BJP and even the PMK, in a rare show of social commitment, launched the preventive measures to help bring down the prevalence, as per an estimate 23 per cent of susceptible population in Chennai gets affected by dengue every year.\nAs per a study published in the PLOS journal: Hidden burden of Dengue in Chennai, in 2015, over 93 per cent of the population is affected. &quot;Going by a conservative estimate let&amp;#39;s assume that there is only one per cent of deaths, even then, there will be 2,880 deaths per year in Chennai alone. So, this is the reality. When people have already conducted a study and the conservative estimate is 2,880 as per the article, we need to devise appropriate measures to tackle the menace,&quot; claims Dr V. Pugazhenthi of Doctors for Safe Environment (Dose).\nThe ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Dengue in Jammu: 88 test positive in 11 days; 336 cases reported since July",
      url    : "http://www.business-standard.com/article/current-affairs/dengue-in-jammu-88-test-positive-in-11-days-336-cases-reported-since-july-117101800395_1.html",
      source : "Business Standard: News Now",
      date   : "18.10.2017",
      desc   : "As many as 88 people were tested  positive for dengue during the past 11 days here, taking the  total number of such patients in the state since July to 336,  officials said.\nOut of the 88 tested positive for dengue since October 7,  71 are residents of the Jammu district, seven of Sabma, six  Kathua, two Udhampur and one each of Rajouri and Doda  districts, they said.\nAt 292, Jammu has recorded the highest number of cases  since July, when it was first reported this year.\nIt was followed by Kathua (12), Samba (11), Rajouri,  Udhampur, Doda (six each), and Poonch and Kishtwar (one each),  the officials said.\nThey said one case of dengue was reported from Kashmir.\nThe officials said 2,023 tests were conducted till  yesterday and so far 336 people including 111 children and 84  women were tested positive for dengue, while 268 reports are  still awaited.\nHowever, there was no fresh case of swine flu which  claimed three lives in the Jammu region since July, the  officials said.\nHea"
    },
    {
      title  : "Plethora of diseases threaten to mar festivities",
      url    : "http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Delhi/plethora-of-diseases-threaten-to-mar-festivities/article19880477.ece",
      source : "Hindu: News",
      date   : "18.10.2017",
      desc   : "Doctors ask people to stay away from Diwali pollution, urge them to take precautionary measures"
    },
    {
      title  : "No side effects in Nilavembu: TN health minister",
      url    : "http://www.deccanchronicle.com/nation/current-affairs/181017/no-side-effects-in-nilavembu-tn-health-minister.html",
      source : "",
      date   : "18.10.2017",
      desc   : "Chennai: Rubbishing the reports in a section of the media that Nilavembu kashayam causes infertility, state health minister Dr Vijayabaskar on Tuesday insisted that the herbal decoction has been tested scientifically and proved effective against several types of fevers, including Dengue and Chickungunya.\n&quot;People should not believe in baseless rumours that Nilavembu kashayam will cause side effects. This herbal medicine has been tested well and used widely in many countries&quot;, the minister said, responding to reports in a section of the media that the use of this medicine could lead to infertility.\nElaborating on the good caused by the herbal medicine in the treatment of fevers, the minister said it had been approved for public use by Jayalalithaa during her tenure as Chief Minister when Chickungunya broke out.\n&quot;We will continue to make elaborate arrangements to distribute Nilavembu kudineer to the public. Also, the government hospitals have been instructed to ensure proper hydration of ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Dengue cases in Hyderabad on rise due to continuous rainfall",
      url    : "http://www.deccanchronicle.com/nation/current-affairs/171017/dengue-cases-in-hyderabad-on-rise-due-to-continuous-rainfall.html",
      source : "",
      date   : "17.10.2017",
      desc   : "<p><strong>Hyderabad:<\/strong> Continuous rainfall over the past few days has sent dengue numbers soaring in Hyderabad, doctors said, on Tuesday.<\/p><p>&#38;quot;There are a lot of Chikungunya and dengue cases and continuous rain has given way to viral flu,&#38;quot; said a doctor at a local hospital, Doctor Shankar.<\/p><p>He added that the stagnant water has led to mosquito breeding, thus, further aggravating the problem.<\/p><p>One of the patients at a hospital said many people have been complaining of health issues due to the weather change.<\/p><p>&#38;quot;My child is suffering from fever from the past one week, people are unable to use roads due to severe waterlogging and there is heavy traffic,&#38;quot; said a resident.<\/p>"
    },
    {
      title  : "Bengaluru: First came the deluge, now comes the disease",
      url    : "http://www.deccanchronicle.com/lifestyle/health-and-wellbeing/171017/first-came-the-deluge-now-comes-the-disease.html",
      source : "",
      date   : "17.10.2017",
      desc   : "With the rains showing no signs of letting up, there has been an outbreak of vector-borne and water-borne diseases across the city. There have been 4,990 cases of dengue and 116 cases of chikungunya since January in Bengaluru alone. Experts blame it on the lack of awareness among people and the general apathy of the BBMP when it comes to keeping the city clean. The problem needs to be dealt with on a war footing. Joyeeta Chakravorty and Chandrashekar G report.\nFirst the deluge and then the disease. Having received a record rainfall, the highest in 115 years this monsoon, which has left its roads and homes flooded and even washed away a few people , Bengaluru is now witnessing the inevitable outbreak of disease. With rain water refusing to run off in some localities with their blocked drains and large potholes, there is a bigger than usual influx of mosquitoes and a spike in vector-borne diseases like dengue and chikungunya. People are also coming down with gastroenteritis, typhoid and jaundice, leaving ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Dengue claims two more lives",
      url    : "http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Delhi/dengue-claims-two-more-lives/article19873788.ece",
      source : "Hindu: News",
      date   : "17.10.2017",
      desc   : "Two more persons, including a 26-year-old Manipuri woman, have succumbed to dengue in the Capital, even as the number of people affected by the vector-borne disease this season has risen to 5,220, as..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Vector-borne diseases spread tentacles",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/punjab/vector-borne-diseases-spread-tentacles/483293.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "17.10.2017",
      desc   : "<p>Chandigarh, October 16\n<\/p><p>Dengue and chikungunya have started tightening their grip around Punjab with a large number of cases being reported from the state in the past two months.\n<\/p><p>According to the latest statistics compiled by the Department of Health and Family Welfare, so far more than 3,500 confirmed cases of dengue have been reported. Besides, around 9,000 suspected cases of dengue have also been reported in this season so far. — TNS <\/p>"
    },
    {
      title  : "Dengue snuffs out two more lives",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/delhi/dengue-snuffs-out-two-more-lives/483238.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "17.10.2017",
      desc   : "Tribune News Service\nNew Delhi, October 16\nTwo more persons, including a 26 -year-old Manipuri woman, have succumbed to dengue in the city even as the number of people affected by the vector-borne disease this season has reached 5,220, according to a municipal report released today.\nThe mosquito-borne tropical disease had claimed its first victim in the city this year, when a 12-year-old boy died of dengue shock syndrome at Sir Ganga Ram Hospital (SGRH) on August 1.\nRhoda Daimai, who was living in Sarita Vihar, South Delhi, died on August 27 of septicaemia and other ensuing complications while 49-year-old Meena Devi, hailing from Bihar, died of dengue on September 2, the report said.\nCivic bodies said Daimai was a resident of a village in Manipur and had come to Delhi seeking treatment while Meena lived in Karawal Nagar in East Delhi. While Meena also died at SGRH, Rhoda succumbed at Holy Family Hospital.\nThe number of malaria and chikungunya cases recorded in the city till October 14 at 1,062 and 683, ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "33 new dengue cases",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/ludhiana/33-new-dengue-cases/481972.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "14.10.2017",
      desc   : "<p>Tribune News Service\n<\/p><p>\n<\/p><p>Ludhiana, October 13\n<\/p><p>As many as 33 fresh dengue cases have surfaced from the city. The total count of confirmed dengue patients has now gone up to 183. The high-risk area from where the maximum cases are being reported is Mundian. Two new cases of chikungunya have also been confirmed.\n<\/p><p>District epidemiologist, Dr Ramesh, said people should be careful. They should not let water collect in and around their houses, he added.\n<\/p><p>“We are regularly educating people regarding symptoms and precautions of dengue. Stress is being laid in the high-risk areas. One can report a suspected case of dengue to nearest government dispensary/hospital or at the Civil Surgeon Office control room phone No. 0161-2444193,” he said. \n<\/p><p> “Test for dengue is being done free of cost at the Civil Hospital in the city,” he added. <\/p>"
    },
    {
      title  : "Delhi district courts lawyers will go on strike tomorrow",
      url    : "http://www.business-standard.com/article/current-affairs/delhi-district-courts-lawyers-will-go-on-strike-tomorrow-117101200359_1.html",
      source : "Business Standard: News Now",
      date   : "12.10.2017",
      desc   : "The lawyers of all six district  courts in the national capital will go on a day-long strike  tomorrow to protest against alleged misconduct of some judges.\n\"The reasons for calling a complete strike are misconduct  of judges with litigants and huge corruption in the judiciary.  We have already given the names of erring judges to the High  Court but no action has been taken so far,\" advocate Jaiveer  Singh Chauhan, Secretary General of the coordination committee  of Delhi bar associations, said.\nIn a unanimous resolution adopted by the Coordination  Committee of all District Court Bar Associations here, it was  alleged that some judges were repeatedly misbehaving with the  lawyers by treating them as subordinates.\nThe strike is likely to paralyse work in all six district  courts at Patiala House, Rohini, Saket, Tis Hazari, Dwarka and  Karkardooma.\nYesterday, the lawyers at the Tis Hazari Court had also  gone on a strike to protest against the alleged \"rude  behaviour\" of a ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Nuh residents to get free insecticide nets",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/haryana/nuh-residents-to-get-free-insecticide-nets/480811.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "12.10.2017",
      desc   : "<p>Nuh residents to get free insecticide nets<\/p>\n\n<p>Chandigarh, October 11<\/p>\n\n<p>Health Minister Anil Vij said that 1.74 lakh insecticide nets would be given away free of cost to control vector-borne diseases in Nuh district. As many as 142 high-risk villages have been identified for this purpose.<\/p>\n\n<p>The minister said that insecticide nets had been received from the Central Government and soon they would be distributed among residents. He said that due to proximity to Delhi, cases of malaria were found to be more in Mewat area as compared to other areas of the state during recent years.<\/p>\n\n<p>Vij said that 72,000 RDT kits had also been sent to Nuh district for rapid testing of blood in case of diseases such as malaria, chikungunya, dengue and others. &#8220;The report of the test conducted on RDT kits can be obtained in 15-20 minutes. As per requirement, such kits have also been provided to Palwal and Yamunanagar districts,&#8221; he said.&#8212;TNS<\/p>"
    },
    {
      title  : "Vector-borne diseases keep Health Dept on toes",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/chandigarh/vector-borne-diseases-keep-health-dept-on-toes/479936.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "10.10.2017",
      desc   : "Tribune News Service\nPatiala, October 9 \nWith the rise in the number of dengue and chikungunya cases, the possibility of an outbreak of these two diseases looms large over Patiala. \nAs many as 366 cases of dengue and 61 cases of chikungunya were reported in the district, which is now keeping the Patiala Health Department on its toes. While dengue cases have started coming in from July, chikungunya cases have been reported from August onwards. \nThough the Health Department has already deployed a rapid response team and a surveillance team in the city to treat patients, the increasing number has become a cause of concern for the authorities. Now, they are taking precautionary measures to ensure that the diseases do not spread in other areas. \nDistrict Epidemiologist Dr Gurmanjeet Kaur said, “Dengue and chikungunya tests are done free of cost at government hospitals. Patients get treatment free of cost.” \nShe said the department had already carried out fogging in areas and the affected persons were getting ..."
    },
    '' // Last item -- needed because previous item ends with a comma
  ]`
```

Comment: Are you have the control of where to put that string that comes from a server?
It looks like a valid JS, so, if you will put it inside `<script>` tag it will be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That server is in no way a JSON API, it's just churning out some JavaScript. Even a tiny change to the response format (such as using semi-colons to end statements) could break an attempt to parse it. I don't know your use case but this all seems like a bad idea to me.

All that said, trying to parse it using `JSON.parse` sounds a lot less dangerous than most of the alternatives. These replaces got it to parse for me:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('response').innerText;

// 1. Convert vars to properties
text = text.replace(/^\s*var\s+(\w+)\s*=/gm, ',"$1":');

// 2. Quote the keys
text = text.replace(/^\s*(\w+)\s*:/gm, '"$1":');

// 3. Get rid of the '' at the end
text = text.replace(/^\s*\},[\n\s]*''.*$/gm, '}');

// 4. Remove the comma that step 1 added at the start
text = text.replace(/^\s*,/g, '');

// 5. Wrap everything in an object
text = '{' + text + '}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script id="response" type="custom">
var _nr_metadata = {
    site_base_url : "http://newsrack.in",
    issue_name    : "iihs_feeds",
    category_name : "Chikungunya",
    listing_url   : "/stories/servelots/iihs_feeds/16"
  }
  var _nr_stories = [
    {
      title  : "Alarm bells ringing:194 dengue cases in 2 weeks in district",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/ludhiana/alarm-bells-ringing-194-dengue-cases-in-2-weeks-in-district/486718.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "25.10.2017",
      desc   : "Tribune News Service\nLudhiana, October 24\nThe number of dengue cases is rapidly increasing in the district as 194 confirmed cases have been recorded by the Health Department in the past two weeks.\nA total of 309 confirmed cases and 524 suspected cases of dengue have been reported in the district this year till Monday. According to the Health Department, cases are mostly being reported from the areas on Chandigarh Road in Ludhiana. These include 33-foot Road, GTB Nagar, Mundian Kalan, Guru Nanak Nagar, GK Estate, Jamalpur, Sectors 32 and 39. There are chances that the number of dengue cases could be higher than official reports, say residents.\nThe department had recorded 31 confirmed dengue cases till September 22 and 115 cases till October 10 in these places. Apart from these cases, as many as 10 confirmed cases of chikungunya, which is also spread by bite of infected aedes mosquitoes, have been reported here this year.\nHealth team finds mosquito larvae in 438 containers\nHealth Inspector Manpreet Singh ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "650 new cases of dengue, 48 of chikungunya",
      url    : "http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Delhi/650-new-cases-of-dengue-48-of-chikungunya/article19908528.ece",
      source : "Hindu: Cities",
      date   : "24.10.2017",
      desc   : "More than 1,000 dengue cases reported so far this month"
    },
    {
      title  : "Dengue cases mount to 5,870 in Delhi",
      url    : "http://indianexpress.com/article/cities/delhi/dengue-cases-mount-to-5870-in-delhi-this-season-4903035/",
      source : "Delhi – The Indian Express",
      date   : "23.10.2017",
      desc   : "<img alt=\"\" border=\"0\" src=\"http://pixel.wp.com/b.gif?host=indianexpress.com&#038;blog=53855017&#038;post=4903035&#038;subd=indianexpressonline&#038;ref=&#038;feed=1\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" />"
    },
    {
      title  : "Nilavembu Kudineer safe, efficacious, confirms National Institute of Siddha",
      url    : "http://www.deccanchronicle.com/lifestyle/health-and-wellbeing/221017/nilavembu-kudineer-safe-efficacious-confirms-national-institute-of-siddha.html",
      source : "",
      date   : "22.10.2017",
      desc   : "Chennai: Nilavembu Kudineer is safe and effective to treat dengue and other viral fevers and one need not have any qualms in consuming this herbal concoction for immediate relief, the National Institute of Siddha (NIS) functioning under the Union Ayush ministry, here has assured. This institute plans to take up a full-fledged study for global reach of this traditional medicine.\nNilavembu kashayam has been in use for over half-a-century at Government Siddha Medical College, Palayamkottai. It is one among the 32 types of internal medicines described in the Siddha system of medicine. &quot;The nilavembu kudineer, now used for the prevention and management of dengue fever has been explained in the Siddha literatures several centuries ago. There are many research papers on nilavembu kudineer for the treatment and prevention of dengue and other viral diseases. Based on the research studies conducted by our National Institute of Siddha, 70 per cent prevention has been proven against dengue and other viral ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Dengue count hits 902 in city",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/chandigarh/dengue-count-hits-902-in-city/485318.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "22.10.2017",
      desc   : "Tribune News Service\nChandigarh, October 21\nWith two deaths at city hospitals, the number of dengue patients has touched 902. According to the Heath Department, the dengue threat will stay for next fortnight.\nDr Gaurav Aggarwal, anti-malaria officer, said 61 malaria and 58 chikungunya cases had also been reported. Last year, the dengue count in the city was 1,246.\n“Next 15 days are crucial. Residents need to be cautious. The weather is congenial for the breeding of aedes aegypti mosquitoes that cause dengue. As the days progress, dengue cases will start declining,” said Dr Gaurav Aggarwal.\nHe added dengue cases were reported from densely populated areas in Dhanas, Ram Darbar, Daddu Majra, Burail besides Sectors 15 and 25. “Since it  is a notifiable disease, the hospitals will have to inform the UT Heath Department within 24 hours,” said Dr Aggarwal. The Heath Department is planning to take strict action against the hospitals for any kind of laxity on their part. “First, we will sent them a notice. It ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "‘Nilavembu kudineer’, a much sought-after elixir",
      url    : "http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/tamil-nadu/nilavembu-kudineer-a-much-sought-after-elixir/article19894225.ece",
      source : "Hindu: National",
      date   : "21.10.2017",
      desc   : "GSMCH has served it to 8.63 lakh persons this year"
    },
    {
      title  : "Two more succumb to vector-borne disease",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/delhi/dengue-sting/484758.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "21.10.2017",
      desc   : "Tribune News Service\nNew Delhi, October 20\nTwo more persons have fallen prey to dengue in the national Capital taking the tally of deaths from the vector-borne disease this season to five.\nThe last two fatalities took place at city government-run Lok Nayak Jayaprakash (LNJP) Hospital which has alone reported over 860 cases of dengue and two deaths.\nAccording to the latest municipal report, tabulated by the South Delhi Municipal Corporation, the number of people affected by the mosquito -borne disease this season till October 14 has reached 5,220.\nA 12-year-old boy, who died due to dengue shock syndrome at the Sir Ganga Ram Hospital on August, was the first victim in the Capital this year. Of the total 5,220 positive cases of dengue, 2,564 were residents of Delhi whereas the rest were from other states. Of the 2,564 Delhi cases, 757 were reported this month, as per the civic body.\nSimilarly till October 14 the figures of malaria and chikungunya stood at 1062 and 683 respectively. According to the report, ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Over 23 per cent of susceptible population gets infected",
      url    : "http://www.deccanchronicle.com/nation/politics/201017/over-23-per-cent-of-susceptible-population-gets-infected.html",
      source : "",
      date   : "20.10.2017",
      desc   : "Chennai: Dengue has generated much attention and debate, as well, but it appears to be rather difficult to manage this menace without collective efforts, it appears.\nAlthough several Opposition parties including the DMK, BJP and even the PMK, in a rare show of social commitment, launched the preventive measures to help bring down the prevalence, as per an estimate 23 per cent of susceptible population in Chennai gets affected by dengue every year.\nAs per a study published in the PLOS journal: Hidden burden of Dengue in Chennai, in 2015, over 93 per cent of the population is affected. &quot;Going by a conservative estimate let&amp;#39;s assume that there is only one per cent of deaths, even then, there will be 2,880 deaths per year in Chennai alone. So, this is the reality. When people have already conducted a study and the conservative estimate is 2,880 as per the article, we need to devise appropriate measures to tackle the menace,&quot; claims Dr V. Pugazhenthi of Doctors for Safe Environment (Dose).\nThe ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Dengue in Jammu: 88 test positive in 11 days; 336 cases reported since July",
      url    : "http://www.business-standard.com/article/current-affairs/dengue-in-jammu-88-test-positive-in-11-days-336-cases-reported-since-july-117101800395_1.html",
      source : "Business Standard: News Now",
      date   : "18.10.2017",
      desc   : "As many as 88 people were tested  positive for dengue during the past 11 days here, taking the  total number of such patients in the state since July to 336,  officials said.\nOut of the 88 tested positive for dengue since October 7,  71 are residents of the Jammu district, seven of Sabma, six  Kathua, two Udhampur and one each of Rajouri and Doda  districts, they said.\nAt 292, Jammu has recorded the highest number of cases  since July, when it was first reported this year.\nIt was followed by Kathua (12), Samba (11), Rajouri,  Udhampur, Doda (six each), and Poonch and Kishtwar (one each),  the officials said.\nThey said one case of dengue was reported from Kashmir.\nThe officials said 2,023 tests were conducted till  yesterday and so far 336 people including 111 children and 84  women were tested positive for dengue, while 268 reports are  still awaited.\nHowever, there was no fresh case of swine flu which  claimed three lives in the Jammu region since July, the  officials said.\nHea"
    },
    {
      title  : "Plethora of diseases threaten to mar festivities",
      url    : "http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Delhi/plethora-of-diseases-threaten-to-mar-festivities/article19880477.ece",
      source : "Hindu: News",
      date   : "18.10.2017",
      desc   : "Doctors ask people to stay away from Diwali pollution, urge them to take precautionary measures"
    },
    {
      title  : "No side effects in Nilavembu: TN health minister",
      url    : "http://www.deccanchronicle.com/nation/current-affairs/181017/no-side-effects-in-nilavembu-tn-health-minister.html",
      source : "",
      date   : "18.10.2017",
      desc   : "Chennai: Rubbishing the reports in a section of the media that Nilavembu kashayam causes infertility, state health minister Dr Vijayabaskar on Tuesday insisted that the herbal decoction has been tested scientifically and proved effective against several types of fevers, including Dengue and Chickungunya.\n&quot;People should not believe in baseless rumours that Nilavembu kashayam will cause side effects. This herbal medicine has been tested well and used widely in many countries&quot;, the minister said, responding to reports in a section of the media that the use of this medicine could lead to infertility.\nElaborating on the good caused by the herbal medicine in the treatment of fevers, the minister said it had been approved for public use by Jayalalithaa during her tenure as Chief Minister when Chickungunya broke out.\n&quot;We will continue to make elaborate arrangements to distribute Nilavembu kudineer to the public. Also, the government hospitals have been instructed to ensure proper hydration of ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Dengue cases in Hyderabad on rise due to continuous rainfall",
      url    : "http://www.deccanchronicle.com/nation/current-affairs/171017/dengue-cases-in-hyderabad-on-rise-due-to-continuous-rainfall.html",
      source : "",
      date   : "17.10.2017",
      desc   : "<p><strong>Hyderabad:<\/strong> Continuous rainfall over the past few days has sent dengue numbers soaring in Hyderabad, doctors said, on Tuesday.<\/p><p>&#38;quot;There are a lot of Chikungunya and dengue cases and continuous rain has given way to viral flu,&#38;quot; said a doctor at a local hospital, Doctor Shankar.<\/p><p>He added that the stagnant water has led to mosquito breeding, thus, further aggravating the problem.<\/p><p>One of the patients at a hospital said many people have been complaining of health issues due to the weather change.<\/p><p>&#38;quot;My child is suffering from fever from the past one week, people are unable to use roads due to severe waterlogging and there is heavy traffic,&#38;quot; said a resident.<\/p>"
    },
    {
      title  : "Bengaluru: First came the deluge, now comes the disease",
      url    : "http://www.deccanchronicle.com/lifestyle/health-and-wellbeing/171017/first-came-the-deluge-now-comes-the-disease.html",
      source : "",
      date   : "17.10.2017",
      desc   : "With the rains showing no signs of letting up, there has been an outbreak of vector-borne and water-borne diseases across the city. There have been 4,990 cases of dengue and 116 cases of chikungunya since January in Bengaluru alone. Experts blame it on the lack of awareness among people and the general apathy of the BBMP when it comes to keeping the city clean. The problem needs to be dealt with on a war footing. Joyeeta Chakravorty and Chandrashekar G report.\nFirst the deluge and then the disease. Having received a record rainfall, the highest in 115 years this monsoon, which has left its roads and homes flooded and even washed away a few people , Bengaluru is now witnessing the inevitable outbreak of disease. With rain water refusing to run off in some localities with their blocked drains and large potholes, there is a bigger than usual influx of mosquitoes and a spike in vector-borne diseases like dengue and chikungunya. People are also coming down with gastroenteritis, typhoid and jaundice, leaving ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Dengue claims two more lives",
      url    : "http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Delhi/dengue-claims-two-more-lives/article19873788.ece",
      source : "Hindu: News",
      date   : "17.10.2017",
      desc   : "Two more persons, including a 26-year-old Manipuri woman, have succumbed to dengue in the Capital, even as the number of people affected by the vector-borne disease this season has risen to 5,220, as..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Vector-borne diseases spread tentacles",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/punjab/vector-borne-diseases-spread-tentacles/483293.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "17.10.2017",
      desc   : "<p>Chandigarh, October 16\n<\/p><p>Dengue and chikungunya have started tightening their grip around Punjab with a large number of cases being reported from the state in the past two months.\n<\/p><p>According to the latest statistics compiled by the Department of Health and Family Welfare, so far more than 3,500 confirmed cases of dengue have been reported. Besides, around 9,000 suspected cases of dengue have also been reported in this season so far. — TNS <\/p>"
    },
    {
      title  : "Dengue snuffs out two more lives",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/delhi/dengue-snuffs-out-two-more-lives/483238.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "17.10.2017",
      desc   : "Tribune News Service\nNew Delhi, October 16\nTwo more persons, including a 26 -year-old Manipuri woman, have succumbed to dengue in the city even as the number of people affected by the vector-borne disease this season has reached 5,220, according to a municipal report released today.\nThe mosquito-borne tropical disease had claimed its first victim in the city this year, when a 12-year-old boy died of dengue shock syndrome at Sir Ganga Ram Hospital (SGRH) on August 1.\nRhoda Daimai, who was living in Sarita Vihar, South Delhi, died on August 27 of septicaemia and other ensuing complications while 49-year-old Meena Devi, hailing from Bihar, died of dengue on September 2, the report said.\nCivic bodies said Daimai was a resident of a village in Manipur and had come to Delhi seeking treatment while Meena lived in Karawal Nagar in East Delhi. While Meena also died at SGRH, Rhoda succumbed at Holy Family Hospital.\nThe number of malaria and chikungunya cases recorded in the city till October 14 at 1,062 and 683, ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "33 new dengue cases",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/ludhiana/33-new-dengue-cases/481972.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "14.10.2017",
      desc   : "<p>Tribune News Service\n<\/p><p>\n<\/p><p>Ludhiana, October 13\n<\/p><p>As many as 33 fresh dengue cases have surfaced from the city. The total count of confirmed dengue patients has now gone up to 183. The high-risk area from where the maximum cases are being reported is Mundian. Two new cases of chikungunya have also been confirmed.\n<\/p><p>District epidemiologist, Dr Ramesh, said people should be careful. They should not let water collect in and around their houses, he added.\n<\/p><p>“We are regularly educating people regarding symptoms and precautions of dengue. Stress is being laid in the high-risk areas. One can report a suspected case of dengue to nearest government dispensary/hospital or at the Civil Surgeon Office control room phone No. 0161-2444193,” he said. \n<\/p><p> “Test for dengue is being done free of cost at the Civil Hospital in the city,” he added. <\/p>"
    },
    {
      title  : "Delhi district courts lawyers will go on strike tomorrow",
      url    : "http://www.business-standard.com/article/current-affairs/delhi-district-courts-lawyers-will-go-on-strike-tomorrow-117101200359_1.html",
      source : "Business Standard: News Now",
      date   : "12.10.2017",
      desc   : "The lawyers of all six district  courts in the national capital will go on a day-long strike  tomorrow to protest against alleged misconduct of some judges.\n\"The reasons for calling a complete strike are misconduct  of judges with litigants and huge corruption in the judiciary.  We have already given the names of erring judges to the High  Court but no action has been taken so far,\" advocate Jaiveer  Singh Chauhan, Secretary General of the coordination committee  of Delhi bar associations, said.\nIn a unanimous resolution adopted by the Coordination  Committee of all District Court Bar Associations here, it was  alleged that some judges were repeatedly misbehaving with the  lawyers by treating them as subordinates.\nThe strike is likely to paralyse work in all six district  courts at Patiala House, Rohini, Saket, Tis Hazari, Dwarka and  Karkardooma.\nYesterday, the lawyers at the Tis Hazari Court had also  gone on a strike to protest against the alleged \"rude  behaviour\" of a ..."
    },
    {
      title  : "Nuh residents to get free insecticide nets",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/haryana/nuh-residents-to-get-free-insecticide-nets/480811.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "12.10.2017",
      desc   : "<p>Nuh residents to get free insecticide nets<\/p>\n\n<p>Chandigarh, October 11<\/p>\n\n<p>Health Minister Anil Vij said that 1.74 lakh insecticide nets would be given away free of cost to control vector-borne diseases in Nuh district. As many as 142 high-risk villages have been identified for this purpose.<\/p>\n\n<p>The minister said that insecticide nets had been received from the Central Government and soon they would be distributed among residents. He said that due to proximity to Delhi, cases of malaria were found to be more in Mewat area as compared to other areas of the state during recent years.<\/p>\n\n<p>Vij said that 72,000 RDT kits had also been sent to Nuh district for rapid testing of blood in case of diseases such as malaria, chikungunya, dengue and others. &#8220;The report of the test conducted on RDT kits can be obtained in 15-20 minutes. As per requirement, such kits have also been provided to Palwal and Yamunanagar districts,&#8221; he said.&#8212;TNS<\/p>"
    },
    {
      title  : "Vector-borne diseases keep Health Dept on toes",
      url    : "http://www.tribuneindia.com/news/chandigarh/vector-borne-diseases-keep-health-dept-on-toes/479936.html",
      source : "The Tribune",
      date   : "10.10.2017",
      desc   : "Tribune News Service\nPatiala, October 9 \nWith the rise in the number of dengue and chikungunya cases, the possibility of an outbreak of these two diseases looms large over Patiala. \nAs many as 366 cases of dengue and 61 cases of chikungunya were reported in the district, which is now keeping the Patiala Health Department on its toes. While dengue cases have started coming in from July, chikungunya cases have been reported from August onwards. \nThough the Health Department has already deployed a rapid response team and a surveillance team in the city to treat patients, the increasing number has become a cause of concern for the authorities. Now, they are taking precautionary measures to ensure that the diseases do not spread in other areas. \nDistrict Epidemiologist Dr Gurmanjeet Kaur said, “Dengue and chikungunya tests are done free of cost at government hospitals. Patients get treatment free of cost.” \nShe said the department had already carried out fogging in areas and the affected persons were getting ..."
    },
    '' // Last item -- needed because previous item ends with a comma
  ]
</script>
```

I've made use of the `m` flag in several of the RegExps. I've assumed that various things can only appear at the start of a line, which is true in your example data but it's so brittle making that assumption.